# iPad: Presenting UIImagePickerController in landscape rotates my other view controllers on dismiss

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

I am presenting a `UIImagePickerController` on iPad with `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`. I know that the other `UIImagePickerControllerSourceType` options need to be presented in a `UIPopoverController`, but I doubt the camera should be.

That being said, I am presenting the camera from a modal view controller that is presented as a `formSheet`. Sometimes when I present the picker, it is shifted down a few pixels, like the status bar pushed it down:

[image]

Next, when I dismiss the picker, it has rotated my `formSheet` modal to portrait mode, but the underlying `UISplitViewController` is still in landscape:

[image]

What is happening here? Am I doing something wrong when presenting a `UIImagePickerController` from a modal form sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what the issue was. I had the following in my `UINavigationController` subclass:

```
// Tell the system which initial orientation we want to have
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Removing that fixed the issue!